# Can't find Paytabs sdk file

Tags: android, sdk

I can't find Pay-tabs library file to import module in Android Studio.

Does anyone have the source or link ? I want use it in payment method [here](https://www.paytabs.com/PayTabs_Android_SDK2.1.pdf) is documentation but it doesn't have example code.

Comment: Did you find SDK?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PayTabActivity.class);
in.putExtra("pt_merchant_email", "merchant@myapp.com"); //this a demo account for
in.putExtra("pt_secret_key", "secret");//Add your Secret Key Here
in.putExtra("pt_transaction_title", "Mr. John Doe");
in.putExtra("pt_amount", "1");
in.putExtra("pt_currency_code", "USD"); //Use Standard 3 character ISO
in.putExtra("pt_shared_prefs_name", "myapp_shared");
in.putExtra("pt_customer_email", "test@example.com");
in.putExtra("pt_customer_phone_number", "0097300001");
in.putExtra("pt_order_id", "1234567");
in.putExtra("pt_product_name", "Samsung Galaxy S6");
in.putExtra("pt_timeout_in_seconds", "300"); //Optional
in.putExtra("pt_address_billing", "Flat 1,Building 123, Road 2345");
in.putExtra("pt_city_billing", "Juffair");
in.putExtra("pt_state_billing", "Manama");
in.putExtra("pt_country_billing", "Bahrain");
in.putExtra("pt_postal_code_billing", "00973"); //Put Country Phone code if Postal
in.putExtra("pt_address_shipping", "Flat 1,Building 123, Road 2345");
in.putExtra("pt_city_shipping", "Juffair");
in.putExtra("pt_state_shipping", "Manama");
in.putExtra("pt_country_shipping", "Bahrain");
in.putExtra("pt_postal_code_shipping", "00973"); //Put Country Phone code if Postal
int requestCode = 0;
startActivityForResult(in, requestCode);
```

SDK link: https://dev.paytabs.com/wp-content/uploads/paytabs-android-sdk-v2.5.zip

Sample link: https://dev.paytabs.com/wp-content/uploads/files/Android_Test_App.zip

Source: https://dev.paytabs.com/docs-apis/#android-sdk

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20577867)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I added a sample for 2.1, but it is already the SDK is changed, and they have to use the last one.